# How to vary the values in the matrix according to z axis value in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I created random connectivity information matrix. From that I have plotted x,y and z axis points in 3D graph .Now I just want to apply the zaxis values in the corresponding connectivity such that where ever 1 is present in connectivity it should be multiplied by corresponding zaxis values (eg: if in conn matrix (1,3)place =1 then it should take particular zaxis values and multiply). But I getting the same values for all the places. Suggestions.

```
%Conncectivity Matrix
success = 0;
n = input('Enter the No. of Nodes');    %size of matrix
k = input('Enter the max connectivity');      %maximal number of 1s
p = 0.5;
Result_Matrix = zeros(n,n);

while (success == 0)
  Result_Matrix = (rand(n,n) < p);
  Result_Matrix(logical(eye(n))) = 0;
  Result_Matrix = max(Result_Matrix, Result_Matrix');
  s = sum(Result_Matrix,1);
  success = 1;
  if min(s) == 0
     success = 0; p = p*2;   % too few 1s, increase p
  end
  if max(s) > k
     success = 0; p = p/2;   % too many 1s, decrease p 
  end
end
m=Result_Matrix;
conn_mat=m;
disp('connection matrix');
disp(m);
[r,c] = find(m);
A = [r,c]

%3D-GRAPH
    PlotSizex=100;
PlotSizey=100;
PlotSizez=-100;
x=PlotSizex*rand(1,n)
y=PlotSizey*rand(1,n)
z=PlotSizez*rand(1,n)
plot3(x(A).', y(A).',z(A).', 'O-')

%Zaxis values multiply with Connectivity
d=zeros(n,n);
z    % values of zaxis

  for i=1:n
        for j=i+1:n            
            d(i,j)= z(i);
            d(j,i)=d(i,j);
        end
  end
 New matrix= d.*m  %d is zaxis values and m is connectivity matrix.
```

Comment: You probably made a typo in your last line, it should be `new_matrix` (without a space)

Comment: It may be easier to answer your question if you provide a fixed example matrix, the outcome you get and the outcome you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do obtain different values in `new_matrix`:

```
new_matrix =
         0  -63.4303  -63.4303         0         0
  -63.4303         0         0  -23.9408         0
  -63.4303         0         0  -24.5725         0
         0  -23.9408  -24.5725         0  -76.5436
         0         0         0  -76.5436         0
```

My connection matrix is:

```
connection matrix
   0   1   1   0   0
   1   0   0   1   0
   1   0   0   1   0
   0   1   1   0   1
   0   0   0   1   0
```

and z values are:

```
z =
  -63.4303  -23.9408  -24.5725  -76.5436  -86.3677
```

I find it strange to multiply the elements in your connection matrix with a single z value, because each element in the connection matrix is related to two points in space (and thus two z values). So, it would make more sense to use the following:

```
for i=1:n
      for j=i:n            
          d(i,j)= z(i)*z(j); % or another combination of z(i) and z(j)
          d(j,i)=d(i,j);
      end
end
```

Comment: I need this new matrix to be updated from n to 0. For eg: 1st time New matrix: d(i,j)= z(i)*z(j);  2nd time New matrix: d(i,j)= z(i)*z(j)/n; 3rd New matrix: d(i,j)= z(i)*z(j)/n-1;... up to New matrix New matrix: d(i,j)= z(i)*z(j)/0; Final New matrix should be all )'s. Can suggest..